# Custom permalink in WP

Tags: wordpress

How to archive the  URL rewrite from `example.com/?special=25` to `example.com/special/25`.

Comment: 'special' is not category,tag,author etc.So the standard permalink options available with WP (like /%postname%/) for custom permalink cannot be used.  'special' is a query field used in a custom function.The function uses $_GET['special'] to get the value and output a special page according to the value....

Answer (score 1):

Check out the WordPress [WP Rewrite class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite). The examples towards the bottom look like they'd get what you are trying to achieve. Sadly not used this before so can't provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more context to the question, it's a little difficult to say; however, based on the URL scheme that you've provided, 'special' appears to be a category, custom post type, or some other [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

If that's the case, then you can use a custom [permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) setting set to: `/%postname%/` and that would take care of it.